# How can we store dropdown selected option string to firestore in android studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have String list as shown I want the selected item to be store in Firestore
Can you please tell me how it should be possible?

I have String list as shown I want the selected item to be store in Firestore
Can you please tell me how it should be possible?

```
public class Student_Register_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etRegEmail,etname,etfathername,etRollno,etdepartment,etadress,etphonenmbr,semester,;
    EditText etRegPassword;

    String[] items={"Shinkiari","Mansehra","Abbottabad","Qalandarabad","Attersheesha","Khaki"};

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteText;
    Button btnRegister;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapteritems;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_register);
        autoCompleteText=findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_txt);

        adapteritems=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,items);

        autoCompleteText.setAdapter(adapteritems);

        autoCompleteText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String item =adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }
        });

        etRegEmail = findViewById(R.id.etRegEmail);
        etRegPassword = findViewById(R.id.etRegPass);

        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        etname = findViewById(R.id.etname);
        etfathername = findViewById(R.id.etfname);
        etRollno = findViewById(R.id.etRollno);
        etdepartment = findViewById(R.id.etdepartment);
        etadress = findViewById(R.id.etadress);
        etphonenmbr = findViewById(R.id.etphonenmbr);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(view -> createUser());


    }

    private void createUser(){
        String email = etRegEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = etRegPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            etRegEmail.setError("Email cannot be empty");
            etRegEmail.requestFocus();
        }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            etRegPassword.setError("Password cannot be empty");
            etRegPassword.requestFocus();
        }else{
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){



                        Toast.makeText(Student_Register_Activity.this, "Student registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        DocumentReference df = firestore.collection("Student").document(user.getUid());

                        //Map is used to store the data
                        Map<String,Object> userinfo = new HashMap<>();
                        userinfo.put("Name",etname.getText().toString());
                        userinfo.put("FName",etfathername.getText().toString());
                        userinfo.put("Email",etRegEmail.getText().toString());
                        userinfo.put("Password",etRegPassword.getText().toString());
                        userinfo.put("semester",etRegPassword.getText().toString());
                        userinfo.put("Transport", adapteritems.toString();
                        userinfo.put("Rollno",etRollno.getText().toString());
                        userinfo.put("Department",etdepartment.getText().toString());
                        userinfo.put("address",etadress.getText().toString());
                        userinfo.put("phone",etphonenmbr.getText().toString());


                        startActivity(new Intent(Student_Register_Activity.this, AdminDashboard.class));


                        //specify if user is student

                        userinfo.put("isStudent","1");
                        df.set(userinfo);



                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Student_Register_Activity.this, "Registration Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?

Comment: Also consider expanding the description of the problem, rather than repeating the same line twice to meet Stack Overflow's requirements. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add selected items from list in user object, If that so you can follow below steps:
first declare global variable for selected

```
String selectedOption;
```

Then save value in on click of list

```
autoCompleteText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                selectedOption =adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }
        });
```

then use that value to save in user object

```
userinfo.put("city",selectedOption);
```